# Visual Studio extension to detect similar C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-analysis, plug-in

I have inherited a large code base, which I would like to refactor.

I notice lost of code which is obviously copy, paste & tweak, which is an obvious candidate for a parametrized function.

Is there any Visual Studio extension which will help me to detect such similar code?

Not that it ***must*** be a VS extension as we are not allowed to install 3rd party software which runs stand-alone, but VS extensions seem to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **Visual Studio Enterprise** offers [Code Clone Detection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh205279(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) out-of-the-box.

So no need of VS extension but a paid Enterprise license is needed.

Comment: My company only pays for professional :-( but, upvote, as you answer may help others